# Combining color schemes for categorical data with linear ranges

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colorbrewer

I'm creating a grouped bar chart and trying to create a color scale for it.

I see the example here for [coloring with a scale](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051).
But let's say the bars in the group could be implicitly contained in smaller groups and should have its own linear color scale.

Let's say I wanted in the example linked the first 3 bars of a group on one linear (blue) color scale and the last 4 bars on a different linear (red) color scale. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **ad hoc** answer, aimed to the example you linked.

One solution is setting the two scales...

```
var scale1 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["lightblue", "darkblue"])
    .domain([0, 2]);

var scale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["red", "darkred"])
    .domain([3, 6]);
```

... and using the indices to choose which one to use:

```
.attr("fill", function(d,i) { return i < 3 ? scale1(i) : scale2(i)});
```

Note that I'm using the domains to match the bars:

```
.domain([0, 2])//goes from the first to the third bar
.domain([3, 6])//goes from the forth to the seventh bar
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/5ba7ad96872b4b5bbc2d212b2ca6e9d0/20e1ed6bb00484f736eab4cad8c221e83bea63d2